# scraping multiple URLs with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, csv, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scrape multiple websites (from a CSV file) and extract certain keywords from their Chrome's **"Inspect Element"-source code** (right clicked on a webpage, then selected Inspect Element).

Right now I can extract certain keywords from their **"View-source"-code** (right clicked on a webpage, then selected View-source via Chrome) with this script:

```
import urllib2
import csv

fieldnames = ['Website', '@media', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js']

def csv_writerheader(path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()

def csv_writer(dictdata, path):
    with open(path, 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(dictdata)

csv_output_file = 'EXPORT_Results!.csv'
# LIST OF KEY WORDS (TITLE CASE TO MATCH FIELD NAMES)
keywords = ['@media', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js']

csv_writerheader(csv_output_file)

with open('top1m-edited.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, lineterminator='\n')
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        # INITIALIZE DICT
        data = {'Website': strdomain}

        if '.nl' in strdomain:
            try:
                req = urllib2.Request(strdomain.strip())
                response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                html_content = response.read()

                # ITERATE THROUGH EACH KEY AND UPDATE DICT
                for searchstring in keywords:
                    if searchstring.lower() in str(html_content).lower():
                        print (strdomain, searchstring, 'found')
                        data[searchstring] = 'found'
                    else:
                        print (strdomain, searchstring, 'not found')
                        data[searchstring] = 'not found'

                # CALL METHOD PASSING DICT AND OUTPUT FILE
                csv_writer(data, csv_output_file)

            except urllib2.HTTPError:
                print (strdomain, 'HTTP ERROR')

            except urllib2.URLError:
                print (strdomain, 'URL ERROR')

            except urllib2.socket.error:
                print (strdomain, 'SOCKET ERROR')

            except urllib2.ssl.CertificateError:
                print (strdomain, 'SSL Certificate ERROR')

f.close()
```

This following code I wrote to get the desired **"Inspect Element"-source code**  from a website to later extract keywords (from multiple websites in the CSV file) using the script above. The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jacob\PycharmProjects\Testing\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.rocmn.nl/')

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")

print(source_code)
```

I would now like to merge the first script with the second one in order to **only** crawl the **"Inspect Element"-source code** (of **all website's** in the CSV) and export the results in a CSV file (as seened in the first script)

I have absolutely no idea where to start to get this working. Please help

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We are here to help solve programming problems but you need to put forth some effort first. Try to combine the two, read some basic programming tutorials, blogs, books, and give it a try. If you can't get it to work, then come back and edit this question to be more specific about what you are having trouble with.

Comment: I know that. I'm just asking for someone to point me to the right direction. At this point, I genuinely don't know where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting keywords from source is not the right approach. Keywords from body part and meta tags matter. Whatever you get, you just need to decrement to 1,

```
private Object getTotalCount(String strKeyword) {
    // TODO Getting total count for given keyword
    // Setting up Javascript executor for executing javascript on a page. Make
    // sure HTMLUNIDriver/Any driver having javascript enabled.
    JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = wdHTMLUnitDriver;
    // System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    // Counting up keyword on body of the web page only
    Object objCount = null;
    try {
        objCount = jsExecutor.executeScript(
            "var temp = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText;\r\nvar substrings = temp.split(arguments[0]);\r\n \r\nreturn (substrings.length);",
            strKeyword);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // System.out.println(obj.toString());
    if (objCount.equals(null))
        return null;
    // Returning total count found by javascript executor.
    return objCount.toString();
}
```